# Differences between Dell SupportAssist and Windows restore points

Tags: windows-10, dell-inspiron, dell-latitude, dell-xps, windows-restore

I've noticed that a "restore point" is created when updating a Dell laptop computer using SupportAssist:

[image]

However, under the `System Protection` tab in `System Properties`, protection for **DELLSUPPORT** is *off* (as its is for all other drives/entries).

[image]

Furthermore, no disk space is reported as being used.

[image]

So what I'm unclear on is whether or not the restore points created from SupportAssist coincide with the DELLSUPPORT entry in System Protection, or is it created somewhere else, and where would that location be? If they do coincide, then why is there no disk usage being reported?

Also, should explicit restore points be avoided in case of potential conflicts with SupportAssist's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any software (Apps or Drivers) can create a Restore Point. Dell is no different in this regard - Lenovo does this as well.

If you need to go to a Restore Point, start with the latest one and if you still have difficulties, go to the one prior.

To your question: It is just fine for Dell to create a Restore Point.

It is good to remember that Restore Points can be cleared and are not always reliable. You can use what is there, or you may need a different correction if needed.

Also the newest points are best and older ones either get cleared or overwritten.

Restore point are OK but may have limits on their value

Comment: I see, though I'm still not able to explicitly restore from a Dell restore point, since protection is off and so the "System Restore" button is disabled in the `System Protection` tab. So I'm not confident in trusting that these restore points are being created correctly, and don't want to find out if or when I may need them.

Comment: Restore points get cleared from time to time and so are not always reliable, so it one is there you can use it, otherwise, different corrections may be needed. I amended my answer in this respect.

Comment: OK, found some restore points - went back to verify on the other laptop that was being upgraded with SupportAssist (though protection is still off for DELLSUPPORT). Figured the one I'm posting from would have some as well since it was updated not too long ago, but as you said, they can be deleted.

Comment: The older a restore point gets the less likely it is to be useful. Generally the newest points are the best ones.

Comment: I image my drives regularly with Macrium anyway, but just wanted to be sure, b/c sometimes it's convenient to just make a restore point before a Windows version update (like 20H2), though I'm not sure how reliable restore parts are for windows update failures that result in system instability, so will probably continue to image instead.

Comment: @samis - You can just uninstall a feature update provided it's within 10-15 days.

Comment: @Ramhound Is the uninstall guaranteed to be clean? Uninstalling to rollback never sits well with me b/c there is always a chance for irreversible corruption, and so an image restore usually gives more piece of mind.

Comment: @samis - Same risk that of using a restore point.